# didn't set vue-eslint-parser, but checked the rules defined in eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, eslint

https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#what-is-the-use-the-latest-vue-eslint-parser-error

From this link I learned that when using eslint-plugin-vue, we should set vue-eslint-parser as eslint parser. If I don't set vue-eslint-parser, it doesn't check the rules defined in eslint-plugin-vue.
To test, I used eslint-plugin-vue but didn't set vue-eslint-parser, which I thought wouldn't report the error, but it still prompted the vue/no-duplicate-attributes error.

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
};
```

```
// testing vue files
<template>
  <MyComponent :foo="abc" foo="dd" />
</template>
```

don't prompted the vue/no-duplicate-attributes error.

Answer (score 0):

Because eslint-plugin-vue has set vue-eslint-parser as its parser in configs/base.js, so we dont have to set it in our .eslintrc.js

[eslint-plugin-vue/lib/configs/base.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzYgy.png)